# Grails - How can I add a <script> inside <head> tag in custom taglib?

Tags: grails

I'm using grails 2.4.5 (with asset pipeline plugin)

How can I add a `<script src="myscript.js">` inside `<head>` tag in custom taglib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asset pipeline plugin provides a custom *taglib* called `AssetsTagLib`. You can invoke any methods of this *taglib* from any custom taglib you wrote just as you would do with the Grails provided *taglib*. The following should or atleast works for me on grails-2.5.1

```
    out << asset.javascript(src: "some-file.js")
```

Check you *taglib* and if you find something like

```
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
```

remove it. Otherwise the output of the custom tag goes to `<body>` instead of `<head>`. I don't know the reason for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not work in grails 2.4.5, the assets goes to `<body>` with `static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'none']`